Opening 0,1,2 descriptors when creating daemon process
APUE (Figure 13.1) says for creating a daemon, after closing all open file descriptors, attach the descriptors 0,1,2 to /dev/null as follows:
/*
* Close all open file descriptors.
*/
if (rl.rlim_max == RLIM_INFINITY)
rl.rlim_max = 1024;
for (i = 0; i < rl.rlim_max; i++)
close(i);
/*
* Attach file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 to /dev/null.
*/
fd0 = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
fd1 = dup(0);
fd2 = dup(0);

My question is: Is it necessary to attach file descriptors 0, 1, 2 or can they all remain unattached?

You will get errors if anything tries to access any of these descriptors, which is hard to avoid. If you have complete control over all reads and writes, there is no need; but opening the file descriptors is way easier than making sure nothing anywhere tries to print a message, emit an error message or diagnostic message, or read standard input.

It also makes it easier to implement a --foreground or --nodaemon option: always write the diagnostics, confident that it's harmless in the normal (daemon) usage.

Thanks, can you explain more about --foreground (--nodaemon) options?

That's when you don't do these things so you can run the thing for debugging or testing and get useful diagnostics etc.
